# Cannot Modify VS2017 on installer.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2017, readyroll

[image]

I'm trying to manually deselect Redgate Readyroll when Modifying the components on installer.exe but I'm always getting this error. And when I click OK, I'm stuck to the "Getting things ready" message. Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: In the visual studio tools menu select extensions and updates.  Find ready roll and press the revert button.   Close visual studio and let it do the update.  Once the update is complete try to remove it again.  Hoping it is not working because a ready roll update was installed

Comment: It turns out that I really messed up my VS2017 installation. I did a complete uninstall and reinstalled it again. Now it's working. Thank to your suggestion tho.